# Biblatex, Oscola, footcite: punctuation

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, punctuation, oscola

I'm quite happy using the Oscola style. However, I do get a strange result using `\footcite`: in addition to the dot added by `\footcite` there is another dot after ibid («ibid..» or, eg, «ibid., 3.») which I cannot explain. My preamble is as follows

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english]{book}
\usepackage[style=oscola]{biblatex}
\usepackage{babel,newcent,textcomp}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\addbibresource{disstryout.bib}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}

% arara: pdflatex: {options: "-file-line-error-style"}
% arara: biber

\newcommand{\latin}[1]{{\it #1}}
```

Thanks very much for your support! (I'm new to Tex but eager to learn.)
J

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. There must be a bug in the Oscola style. Not the best solution, but you can add `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{ibidem={ibid}}` in your preamble to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks very much, karl koeller. This is a nice workaround for the bug, I think. In any case, for `\footcite[3]{some-article}`, I get «ibid, 3.» Now, if you could help directing me to a solution that would allow me to get «ibid 3», that'd be perfect :)

Comment: Off-topic: If you are really going to write Latin text in your document, you should use `babel`: `\usepackage[latin, english]{babel}` (for proper hyphenation) and then `\newcommand{\latin}[1]{\foreignlanguage{latin}{\emph{#1}}}`.  The use of `\it` is not recommended for LaTeX users.  And hard-coding Latin into italics (`\textit`) means you won't get proper emphasis nesting: compare your command with the one given here in the following text: `\emph{This is not Latin: \latin{lorem ipsum}}`

Comment: @jon thank you, I will gladly use your suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The root of all evil, so to speak, lies in `oscola.bbx`, more specifically the redefinition of `postnote` (l. 1670)

```
\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{%
  \ifboolexpr {test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} or
               test {\iftoggle{cbx@postnoteprinted}}}%
    {\midsentence}%<---- that's the little bugger
    {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumequal{\value{bbx@suppresspostnotedelim}}{1}}}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \bbx@resetpostnotedelim}
       {\setunit{\postnotedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{postnotepagination}}%
     \global\toggletrue{cbx@postnoteprinted}}
```

You can add the following to your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{%
  \ifboolexpr {test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} or
               test {\iftoggle{cbx@postnoteprinted}}}%
    {}%<---- nothing to see here
    {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumequal{\value{bbx@suppresspostnotedelim}}{1}}}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \bbx@resetpostnotedelim}
       {\setunit{\postnotedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{postnotepagination}}%
     \global\toggletrue{cbx@postnoteprinted}}
\makeatother
```

if you notice any adverse effect or insist on `\midsentence`, you can exchange the marked empty pair of curly braces `{}` for `{\midsentence\nopunct}`.

The MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=oscola,
    natbib=true,
    sorting=nyt,
    maxbibnames=10,
    maxcitenames=2
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{%
  \ifboolexpr {test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} or
               test {\iftoggle{cbx@postnoteprinted}}}%
    {}
    {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumequal{\value{bbx@suppresspostnotedelim}}{1}}}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \bbx@resetpostnotedelim}
       {\setunit{\postnotedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{postnotepagination}}%
     \global\toggletrue{cbx@postnoteprinted}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  Go\footcite{wilde} and again\footcite[123]{wilde} that's it\footcite{wilde}.
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

then yields
[image]

---

### Edit

The situation is more complicated than I thought. Punctuation is one of the features that is language dependent, so the output here looks different in different language. (You might notice that the MWE above used `ngerman`, which is probably not what you want.)

So an `american` document (and an `english` one for that matter) will without modifications yield the following

[image]

As you can see, there is an awful lot of double punctuation.
You will find that footnote 8, however, does not suffer from double punctuation, this seems to be down to the way `oscola` handles postnotes in the first cite. If footnote 7 had contained a postnote, then footnote 8 would have gotten the superfluous comma (try it!).

A `british` document, meanwhile, looks like this

[image]

Note that there is no double punctuation, but the "ibid" is not (always) followed by a dot.

In an `american` (or `english`) document the following modifications seem to acheive what you want.

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{footcite}{%
  \bbx@resetpostnotedelim%<----- reset the tracker here ...
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \ifboolexpr {test {\ifciteseen} or test {\ifciteibid}}
    {\ifboolexpr {test {\iffieldundef{shorthand}} 
                  or test {\bbx@ifnottrackingcites}}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
          {\usebibmacro{footcite:ibid}\bbx@unsetpostnotedelim}%<-- ... so we can set it here
          {\usebibmacro{footcite:note}}}%
       {\usebibmacro{footcite:shorthand}}}
    {\usebibmacro{footcite:full}%
     \usebibmacro{footcite:save}}}
    
\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{%
  \ifboolexpr {test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} or
               test {\iftoggle{cbx@postnoteprinted}}}%
    {}%
    {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumequal{\value{bbx@suppresspostnotedelim}}{1}}}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \bbx@resetpostnotedelim}
       {\setunit{\postnotedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{postnotepagination}}%
  \global\toggletrue{cbx@postnoteprinted}}
\makeatother
```

The MWE

```
\documentclass[american]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=oscola]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{footcite}{%
  \bbx@resetpostnotedelim
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \ifboolexpr {test {\ifciteseen} or test {\ifciteibid}}
    {\ifboolexpr {test {\iffieldundef{shorthand}} 
                  or test {\bbx@ifnottrackingcites}}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
          {\usebibmacro{footcite:ibid}\bbx@unsetpostnotedelim}
          {\usebibmacro{footcite:note}}}%
       {\usebibmacro{footcite:shorthand}}}
    {\usebibmacro{footcite:full}%
     \usebibmacro{footcite:save}}}
    
\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{%
  \ifboolexpr {test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} or
               test {\iftoggle{cbx@postnoteprinted}}}%
    {}
    {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumequal{\value{bbx@suppresspostnotedelim}}{1}}}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \bbx@resetpostnotedelim}
       {\setunit{\postnotedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{postnotepagination}}%
  \global\toggletrue{cbx@postnoteprinted}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  Go\footcite[8]{wilde} and again\footcite[123]{wilde} that's it\footcite{wilde}.
  
  And another\footcite[4]{baez/article} cite\footcite{baez/article}, again \footcite[23]{baez/article}.
  
  The Greek philosophers\footcite{aristotle:anima} must have known\footcite[9]{aristotle:anima} something\footcite{aristotle:anima}.
  
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, moeve. This solves the problem for `\footcite{some-article}` which now results in «ibid.» as it should. However, if I put `\footcite[3]{some-article}` it returns «ibid., 3.» whereas I'd like it to be «ibid 3.» Furthermore, if I use `{\midsentence\nopunct}`as you suggested, the first footnote citing the article is without a period at the end (as in your MWE result where the nicely chosen book in footnote 1 is lacking a dot at the end…) I'm  very grateful for your support! (and hope to equally contribute eventually). J

Comment: Your edit works perfectly, I thank you very much indeed. It gives exactly the citation that is required by Oscola, this should be communicated to the biblatex-oscola team.

Comment: @moeve I was trying to work with oscola.bbx to get rid of the last flaw, namely that if a source is cited for a second time but not subsequently the footnote refers to the first, full footnote by, eg, `see n. 1`. The correct way of doing it, however, would be `see n 1`, so once more one period too many. Could you help with that, too? Thanks again.

Comment: @Jonas Well, in that case, the best option is to change the localisation string `seenote` from `{see n\adddot}` to `{see n}` (by `\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{seenote = {see n}}`). You might also want to have a look at `english-oscola.lbx`, but that might be too much for you.

Comment: @moeve and the other experts: The odyssey continues as I was able to change a few minor things, but now I am stuck again. When I cite a book with three or more editors, the penultimate and the ultimate editors are displayed as follows `X, Y, and Z` whereas I would like to see it as `X, Y and Z` or `X, Y, Z` or `X/Y/Z`. I couldn't identify the right line in english-oscola.lbx.

Comment: @Jonas I'm quite optimistic this question will already have been answered, so look around if you can find it. If you can't find it or the solutions you found did not float your boat, you should ask a new question. (If you want to figure it out yourself, search for `\finalnamedelim` and `\finalandcomma` in [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf))

Comment: Huge thanks for sorting out that muddle. I made one tiny correction: `\midsentence\nopunct` doesn't do the job, I think: it ends up clobbering full points where there is no postnote.

Comment: @PaulStanley Thank you for catching that. Unfortunately, the whole punctuation tracking business always finds new ways to surprise me, and there are some situations where I'm just not sure why things work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I now have the result I was looking for, ie multiple authors or editors are separated by an `and` without any comma if there are not more than three names, and if there are more than three names, the first is given followed by an `et al` without punctuation.

The code is as follows, and as it is certainly rather messy I'd be grateful for any suggestions:

```
\documentclass[english]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,latin]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=oscola,maxnames=3]{biblatex}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\DisemulatePackage{index}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalandcomma}{}

\AtBeginBibliography{
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{
    \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
    \renewcommand*{\finalandcomma}{}
}

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{
    \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    and
    test \ifmorenames
  }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
       {\finalandcomma}
       {}
     \andothersdelim\bibstring{andothers}}
    {}}

\newtoggle{incitation}
\pretocmd{\citesetup}{\toggletrue{incitation}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\bibsetup}{\togglefalse{incitation}}{}{}
\newcommand{\biband}{\iftoggle{incitation}{and}{and}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{ibidem={ibid}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{seenote = {see n}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{editor = {ed}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{editors = {eds}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{andothers = {et al}}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{footcite}{%
  \bbx@resetpostnotedelim
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \ifboolexpr {test {\ifciteseen} or test {\ifciteibid}}
    {\ifboolexpr {test {\iffieldundef{shorthand}} 
                  or test {\bbx@ifnottrackingcites}}
       {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
          {\usebibmacro{footcite:ibid}\bbx@unsetpostnotedelim}
          {\usebibmacro{footcite:note}}}%
       {\usebibmacro{footcite:shorthand}}}
    {\usebibmacro{footcite:full}%
     \usebibmacro{footcite:save}}}

\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{%
  \ifboolexpr {test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} or
               test {\iftoggle{cbx@postnoteprinted}}}%
    {}
    {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumequal{\value{bbx@suppresspostnotedelim}}{1}}}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \bbx@resetpostnotedelim}
       {\setunit{\postnotedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{postnotepagination}}%
  \global\toggletrue{cbx@postnoteprinted}}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}{\printtext}{\printtext[parens]}{}{}
```

Comment: A few comments: This will result in "Author and Buthor and Cuthor", it looks odd to me, but if that's what you want OK. You do not have to redefine `\finalnamedelim`, `\renewcommand*{\finalandcomma}{}` is enough. The `\AtBeginBibliography{` portion is unnecessary since these definitions are exactly as the global ones. The redefinition of `name:andothers` seems superfluous; it is actually the original code, as far as I can see. The whole `incitation` code from `\newtoggle{incitation}` to `\newcommand{\biband}{\iftoggle{incitation}{and}{and}}` does not seem to do anything, you can get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the `\AtBeginBibliography{`part and the `incitation` portion. However, if I remove `\finalnamedelim`, the comma after the final `and` when listing authors returns, and if I remove the redefinition of `name:andothers`, it results in `et al.` and not `et al`, the latter of which is what Oscola requires.

Comment: Mhhh, that's interesting, the `oscola` files do not modify `name:andothers` and your definition is exactly the same as in `biblatex.def` save for one `%` that's missing in your code. The `\finalandcomma` redefinition is overridden by the language file, so indeed `\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}` does the job, you can remove the line `\renewcommand*{\finalandcomma}{}` as it is useless in effect.

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{\let\finalandcomma=\empty}` seems to work, so you can replace `\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}` and `\renewcommand*{\finalandcomma}{}` by `\AtBeginDocument{\let\finalandcomma=\empty}`.

Comment: @moewe, thank you. Strangely, the comma before the `and` in `Author A, Author B, and Author C` returns, however, if I replace the lines as you suggest… so, I'll stick with it

Comment: Mhhh ... strange. Still, if it works, it works!